# Seeding table with multiple Relations laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, exception, seed, laravel-seeding

Hello i'm new to laravel 
and I want to seed a table with multiple relations like this

```
       for ($i=0; $i < 30; $i++) {
        Product::create([
            'title' => $faker->sentence(1),
            'slug' => $faker->slug,
            'subtitle' => $faker->sentence(3),
            'categorie' => $faker->sentence(1),
            'ville' => $faker->sentence(1),
            'description' => $faker->text,
            'price' => $faker->numberBetween(15, 300),
            'duration' => $faker->numberBetween(15, 300),
            'image' => '//imgur.com/a/WhaAC9O'
        ])->categories()->attach([
            rand(1, 4),
            rand(1, 4)
        ])
```

but when I add this part, it throws an exception while seeding

```
->villes()->attach([
            rand(1, 1),
            rand(1, 1)
        ])
```

;

this is the exception :

Call to a member function villes() on null

what should I do ?

this is the Product.php

```
class Product extends Model
{


 public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
}

public function villes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Ville');
}
```

}

Comment: Are you chaining the methods like categories()->attach([
            rand(1, 4),
            rand(1, 4)
        ])->villes()->attach([rand(1,1)]); ?

Comment: add your relationship code here. so will get better idea what is an issues are there.

Comment: i'm trying to chaine  product to category and also product to Ville

Answer (score 0):

i can not agree on overall seeding plan,seeding must be more solid, there is a possibility that this  category or ville doesn't existed ...

but for the error, it shows up because [attach](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Concerns/InteractsWithPivotTable.html#method_attach) method returns null

```
for ($i=0; $i < 30; $i++) {
  $product=  Product::create([
        'title' => $faker->sentence(1),
        'slug' => $faker->slug,
        'subtitle' => $faker->sentence(3),
        'categorie' => $faker->sentence(1),
        'ville' => $faker->sentence(1),
        'description' => $faker->text,
        'price' => $faker->numberBetween(15, 300),
        'duration' => $faker->numberBetween(15, 300),
        'image' => '//imgur.com/a/WhaAC9O'
    ]);
$product->categories()->attach([
            rand(1, 4),
            rand(1, 4)
        ]);
$product->villes()->attach([
            rand(1, 1),
            rand(1, 1)
        ]);
}
```